# Running Python on remote server on schedule

Tags: python, automation, systemd, remote-server, cron-task

I want to build a Python script which should go to web every day at 1 pm, do some job (some web-scraping) and save a result to a file.

It will be deployed on a Linux server.

I am not sure what technology to use to run it on schedule.

What comes to mind:

1. Run it with a cron job scheduler. Quick and dirty. Why bother with any other methods?
2. Run it as a service with a systemd / systemctl (I never did this but I just know there is such possibility and I have to google for a specific implementation). Is this something to be considered as best practice?
3. Other methods?

Since, I never did this, I don't know the pros and cons of every method. May be it's just a one way of doing this properly? Please share your experience.

Comment: Open up crontab and schedule it for 13 * * * *

Answer (score 0):

I use cron job to run a schedule task it works awesome with me.